# How to customize "myLocationButton" of Google Maps for iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm a newbie in iOS development. I want to create a custom button with the same functionality as the default button (`myLocationButton`) in Google Maps SDK for iOS. Can I do that? 
I can create the button but I don't know how to add action to track my current location and show the marker in the center of the screen. I'm using Swift 3.

[image: -Here is the image-]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could implement the action like so:

```
func gotoMyLocationAction(sender: UIButton)
{
    guard let lat = self.mapView.myLocation?.coordinate.latitude,
          let lng = self.mapView.myLocation?.coordinate.longitude else { return }

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat ,longitude: lng , zoom: zoom)
    self.mapView.animate(to: camera)
}
```

This center your map to your current position if they exists. Hope that helps.

Be sure the position detection on your `GMSMapView` is enabled

```
self.mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 7):

Update Swift 4 for @Thomas answer, with GoogleMapSDK 2.7.0

```
func didTapMyLocationButton(for mapView: GMSMapView) -> Bool {

    guard let lat = googleMapView.myLocation?.coordinate.latitude,
        let lng = googleMapView.myLocation?.coordinate.longitude else { return false }

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat ,longitude: lng , zoom: userMapZoom)
    googleMapView.animate(to: camera)

    return true

}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed!